# ext4 raid5 corrupt group descriptor

Tags: linux, raid, ext4

I have a raid5 NAS on Open Media Vault, with 3x 2To disks.

A few days ago I've inserted a spare disk from another raid.
I did not see it at the beginning, but I think that changed disks order.
Then I run cfdisk to make a new volume, maybe on the wrong /dev/.
I think, not sure of that.

Nothing was wrong until the system got rebooted.

Now I'm stuck at boot with a very bad message

journalctl :

```
Dec 27 20:44:13 pacem systemd-fsck[362]: /dev/md1: One or more block group descriptor checksums are invalid.  FIXED.
Dec 27 20:44:13 pacem systemd-fsck[362]: /dev/md1: Group descriptor 0 checksum is 0x0000, should be 0xbd42.
Dec 27 20:44:13 pacem systemd-fsck[362]: /dev/md1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Dec 27 20:44:13 pacem systemd-fsck[362]: (i.e., without -a or -p options)
```

Raid seems to be fine

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md1 : active raid5 sdd1[0] sdc1[3] sdb1[1]
  3907026624 blocks super 1.0 level 5, 32k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
  bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Also I've check `dumpe2fs /dev/md1 | grep -i superblock`
It says `ext2fs_read_bb_inode: A block group is missing at inode table' but I see a list of superblocks backup.

Is there any chance to restore this filesystem ?
What's the best thing to try first ?

Comment: I'm currently copying 2 of 3 array devices to images on a big disk using dd
then I'll trying to assemble md array from images (with a missing disk) , then try to fsck and recover ext4..

Comment: used images to assemble a raid. after fdisk has done its job, it seems that my volume is empty... but not ! my main directories are listed in subfolders of lost+found.

Answer (score 0):

As I successfully retrieved my data, I will answer my own question, this maybe could be useful to someone.

Warning  :

1. I've been confused by the fact that when "repaired" after `fsck`, root directories of my drive where "hidden" inside `lost+found` directory
2. I will describe here how I managed to "safely" try to repair my faulty ext4
3. As always : Keep backup of ALL data. My partial backup was a pain, I did not expect that..
4. Hot swap drive bay was a real advantage in my situation : no need to reboot when swapping between drives

Prepare

- I've bought a 6TB drive (named backup)
- Once backup drive in place and formatted (etx4), I've duplicated 2 of 3 of the raid5 drives, using dd :`dd if=/dev/sdb of=/mnt/backup/sdb1.img ; dd if=/dev/sdc of=/mnt/backup/sdc1.img`. Took 10 hours @ 110mb/s
- Switch to another PC with backup drive
- Using loopback devices, created devices with previous images, as a sort of virtual drive
- `losetup -f` (initiate /dev/loopX if missing)
- `losetup /dev/loop0 /mnt/backup/sdb1.img` creates /dev/loop0
- `losetup /dev/loop1 /mnt/backup/sdc1.img` creates /dev/loop1
- Now, starting a new raid5, with only 2 drives `mdadm --assemble --run /dev/md1 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1`. It should be marked with a `[UU_]` when display `cat /prod/mdstat`
- Note that later, once `/dev/loopX is created, mdadm might create`/dev/md127`on his own. you can stop it with`mdadm --stop /dev/md127`to create your own`/dev/mdX`

Repair

- Now it's time to try repairing filesystem, since trying to mount `/dev/md0` shows a `Group descriptor 0 checksum is 0x0000, should be 0xbd42 ...`
- run `fsck.ext4 /dev/md0`
- To answer all questions with yes, hit key `a`
- Takes a few hours, 2 cycles of fsck maybe needed (when repaired, fsck is restarted from the begining)

Mount and backup

- Then I could run `mount /dev/md0 /mnt/data`
- But `/mnt/data` is empty, except `lost+found/` !
- It seems that the root directories are somewhat correupted, and then all my data is stored inside `lost+found/#17xxxxxx` folders !
- `ls -la /mnt/data/lost+found/\#17*` to display all content
- .. Then backup again to my new raid (bought in between 3x 4TB)

Resources :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/322070/how-can-i-fix-mounting-my-data-drive-after-a-crash

https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later

https://superuser.com/questions/962395/assemble-3-drive-software-raid5-with-one-disk-missing